# Possible to dynamically change rows in web reporting pivot table?

Tags: iccube

Setting up a pivot table via the web reporting tool, you must specify all levels of rows that are to be used. There is a use case where the rows displayed or used to show the data makes sense to dynamically set, or switch around. Is this possible, or does the whole web report need to be edited? (The equivalent of editing a pivot table rows in Excel)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: Suppose I have a data set of populations. I can create the following different views on the data:
- Rows are countries
- Rows are cities
- Rows are countries, expanding on a country shows containing cities, etc, with column being sum of population.

If I have a data set that can be split using very many metrics (country / continent / city / rural / suburb / zip code / area code / latitude range), I can't predict which rows my users will want to see at all times. In Excel, for example, they can change the setup of the pivot table hierarchy easily. Is this possible?

Comment: Cell rendering is based on columns idx not rows. If we need to be flexible on the columns we could create a 'gizmo' -> implementation of the interface that defines the behaviour with parameters the user can setup. But the latest is more complicated, indeed.

Comment: Sorry, that's not completely clear - can a user change the rows that are used to break down / group the data? Even if changing columns is tougher, modifying at least the rows is helpful.

Comment: You can create a 'Actions/Buttons' widget with a list of sets that represents the 'rows' a user can switch too. When a user clicks he is changing the MDX setting the rows with the value of the button widget. Check the very bottom of http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Shopping%20Cart%20I